# Could not start PostgreSQL server

Tags: postgresql, server, port

I downloaded postgres app and when I create new server on port 5432 try to start it I get an error:

```
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

Then I have `Open Server Log` button below it and when I click on it I get:

```
2022-09-25 17:29:33.872 CEST [1054] LOG:  database system is shut down
2022-09-25 17:30:44.244 CEST [1068] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.5 on aarch64-apple-darwin20.6.0, compiled by Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9), 64-bit
2022-09-25 17:30:44.245 CEST [1068] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2022-09-25 17:30:44.245 CEST [1068] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2022-09-25 17:30:44.246 CEST [1068] FATAL:  could not open lock file "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock": Permission denied
2022-09-25 17:30:44.246 CEST [1068] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Comment: This needs more information 1) Postgres version. 2) How did you install Postgres? 3) Did you run `pg_ctl` as OS superuser or as normal user?

Answer (score 0):

The permissions on your `/tmp` are messed up. They should be so that everybody could create files there:

```bash
$ ls -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 24 root root 620 Sep 26 07:26 /tmp
```

I would reinstall the operating system and start again.